# Ban character from all textareas on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've got a problem. As soon as I enter this little f****r  --> ' <-- in my textarea which are sent to a database via AJAX, it stops working. So if I for example enter:

> I am a little gnome and I'm glad to meet you. Hug me!

The database will only receive:

> I am a little gnome and I

So.. Can I limit all textareas on the page to like A-Z + ÅÄÖ + . , + other regularly used characters which don't ruin my stuff? I am using `onchange` for the AJAX request, and another eventlistener for `keyup` to make it work on Safari, if that's of any importance to anyone!

SQL-injection vulnerability, got it. I'm scared, and have stuff to do. Thanks for all answers thus far.

Comment: We need some code. You should be able to send apostrophes without problems, but it's tough to debug without seeing what you've got so far.

Comment: You'd be **much** better off fixing your server-side database code. Sounds like you've got a serious SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Pointy I know I do, but this will never be used in any real cases. So it's and SQL thing? :/

Comment: Try changing `var radioValue = PassedComment.value` to `var radioValue = $(PassedComment).serialize()`. The problem might also be with your php script, but I'm guessing it's an encoding issue.

Comment: It is a misuse of SQL from PHP thing (a.k.a. SQL injection vulnerability). [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) hits again! We'd need the bit of code where you are constructing your SQL query - that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Yes. You're forming the SQL to update the database without sanitizing the content first, either by using a prepared statement (the right way) or doing it textually (the questionable way).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @epascarello: No no no no. It has nothing to do with URI. And even if `encodeURIComponent` escaped values in a way that was sensible for MySQL, you would still be vulnerable to people hand-crafting clientside requests. Escaping needs to be done on the serverside.

Comment: OP still needs to use it... Throw a & into it and BAM, another issue besides the SQL Injection.

Comment: @epascarello: You're right, I didn't even notice, I assumed he was using `$.ajax` `data`... which is a better idea than manually messing with `encodeURIComponent`, I'd say, since you're using jQuery anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Note

I can see you're starting out, and it's great! You've always gotta find a bug to learn new stuff, and you're learning about SQL Injections now. If I could suggest something, you'd be best to start at [**PHP The Right Way**](http://www.phptherightway.com/), it'll help you a truckload.

---

You're PHP script (*that inserts this data into a database*) is not sanitized correctly.

We can't do much without seeing your associated code. But I take it you're using `mysql_*`/`mysqli_*` functions? We'll the former one is **deprecated** and removed as of PHP7!

You should start learning either of the following two prepared statement types:

- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)
- [Mysqli Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

From what I assume, you want to **escape** the string:

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);
```

Although, there are still ways around the above escape; your database can still be hacked via SQL Injection, which is not what you want.

As [*noted by Armadan*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667727/ban-character-from-all-textareas-on-the-page/34667780?noredirect=1#comment57081379_34667780), to back up my statement above, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is still by-passable in certain cases, read these:

- [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2518525)
- [Bypassing mysql_escape_string while SQL injection attacks](http://blackburnmoonlit.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/bypassing-mysqlescapestring-while-sql.html)

---

Taking the code you've supplied, you'd use `prepare()` and `execute()`:

```
if(isset($_GET['comment1'])) {
    if($mysqli = connect_db()) {
        $insertcomment1 = $_GET['comment1'];
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE result SET c1=?");
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
            die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
        }
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $insertcomment1);
        // execute
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
             die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
        }
        // handle the rest here.
    }
}
```

You'd be doing something like the above. You're best to read up on the following in relation to prepared statements using MySQLi:

- [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)
- [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
- [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: @Amadan [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2518525) or [this](http://blackburnmoonlit.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/bypassing-mysqlescapestring-while-sql.html)

Comment: I added a bit of code from the php file. Again, this site will never really see the light of day, but could be good to know for future reference anyway. How would I make this code safe (see edit)?

Comment: @JohnSmith please see the updated answer.

Comment: Ohhh boy, I've got some reading up to do.. Thank you very much Darren.

Comment: @JohnSmith You'll be right mate, just keep pushing through and asking away! Only way to learn is from your own mistakes!